# ASP.NET <form runat=server> breaks jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In a nutshell, it seems that when an ASP.NET page has the `<form runat=server>` tag, it's breaking some jQuery scripts. Here's an example:

I have a very simple page that only has a checkbox, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox01" />
```

and a call to a jQuery function like this:

```
<script language=javascript>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[type=checkbox]").iphoneStyle();
    });
</script>
```

Please, note that I'm not referencing any IDs specifically. The jQuery call is for all checkboxes found in the page.

This is working fine, and the jQuery call works as expected. But...

When I enclose the checkbox in a ASP.NET form, like below:

```
<form runat="server" id="form1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox01" />
</form>
```

The jQuery call stops working, and I get the JavaScript error ***"Object doesn't support property or method 'iphoneStyle'"***.

Again, please note that I'm not referencing any specific IDs, nor is the checkbox an ASP.NET (runat=server) control -- it's just a plain old checkbox.

I can't seem to track this problem down. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to see if the selector is working? `console.log($("[type=checkbox]"));`

Comment: Yes, the selector is working. Though, I tested this using a diferent approach. I changed the call to `$("[type=checkbox]").hide();` and the checkbox is being hidden as expected.

Comment: Even though your selector is working, i suggest changing it to `$('[type="checkbox"]').` And from a performance point of view, its good to use a container if youre not selecting an ID directly. Something like `$('#form1 input[type="checkbox"]').`

Comment: Thanks, @Johan. I changed the code as you suggested. The behavior is still the same, though.

Comment: Have you checked out the net tab in firebug/chrome developer tools and verified that the script for iphoneStyle() is correctly loaded?

Comment: looks like the problem is with how the `iphoneStyle()` plugin is being imported

Comment: @Johan, I just checked, and the JS file that contains the iphoneStyle is being loaded correctly.

Comment: @zgood, I'm also suspecting this. The only lead I have is that when the `<form runat=server>` is in the page, I get a whole bunch of **WebResource.axd** scripts. I think this is what is interfering with the jQuery plugin. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are your `<script>` imports in the DOM and what do they look like? Are you using MasterPages?

Comment: @zgood Yes, MasterPages are involved. The imports are done like so: `<script src="<% =ResolveUrl("./Script/jquery-1.6.3.js") %>" language=javascript></script>` and `<script src="<% =ResolveUrl("./Script/iphone-style-checkboxes.js") %>" language=javascript></script>`. This is inside the `<head>` tag of the MasterPage.

Comment: hmmm... this is a toughy. When you said you enclose the checkbox in an ASP.NET form is this on the child page? A MasterPage will usually have it's own ASP.NET form and you are only allowed one ASP.NET form or else you'll get an error. I don't think this is the problem I'm just asking for clarification. Also, is this in a local environment or a live production environment?

Comment: Some other must be your problem because I just make a page with that and is working perfect.

Comment: @zgood Double-checked, there's no `<form>` in the MasterPage, only the child pages. Anyway, made some progress. I created a plain ASP.NET page, that does not use a MasterPage, and this page is working with and without the `<form>` tag. So, this narrows it down to a conflit with MasterPages... Any ideas?

Comment: @Aristos I've just created a plain ASP.NET page, that does not use MasterPages and it's working. It must be some conflict specific with MaterPages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem. jQuery itself would work but any plugin I added would not. I kept getting "Object doesn't support property or method..." complaints. The resolution was to move the  references to the jQuery plugins from the Site.Master aspx page to the "main" page where I was using the jQuery plugin. I thought I was being clever by putting all my script references in the Site.Master but I was too clever afterall.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script like this. it works for me

```
  <script language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
      $('input:checkbox').iphoneStyle();
      });
  </script>
```